# link not redirecting to another page

Tags: php, html

i have a table where one column is for edit button the code for it is

```
echo "<td><a href=\"a_add_fav_vendor.php?id=".$data['id']."\"><input type='image' src='images/icn_edit.png' title='Edit'></a></td> ";
```

i don't know why but the link is not working. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with it

the code for entire table is

```
<form method="post" action="sendmail.php">  
    <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
            <?php
                $reload = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?tpages=" . $tpages;

                    echo "<table class='tablesorter' cellspacing='0'> ";
                        echo "<thead>
                                    <tr> 
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th>Shopname</th> 
                                        <th>Instagram account</th>
                                        <th>Favourite</th>
                                        <th>Edit</th>
                                        <th>Delete</th> 
                                    </tr> 
                              </thead>";

                            for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) 
                                {
                                    if ($i == $total_results) 
                                        {
                                            break;
                                        }

                                        mysqli_data_seek($result, $i);

                                        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                                        echo "<tr " . $cls . ">";
                                            echo '<td></td>';
                                            ?><td> <input name="checkbox[<?php echo $data['id']?>]" type="checkbox"> </td>
                                            <?


                                            echo '<td>' . $data['fullname_shopname'] . '</td>';
                                            echo '<td>' . $data['username_instagramacnt'] . '</td>';

                                            if($data['staffpick']=='yes')
                                                {
                                                     echo '<td>Yes</td>';
                                                }
                                            else
                                                {
                                                     echo '<td>No</td>';
                                                }                                                           
                                            echo "<td><a href=\"a_add_fav_vendor.php?id=".$data['id']."\"><input type='image' src='images/icn_edit.png' title='Edit'></a></td> ";

                                            echo "<td><a onclick=\"return confirm('delete this record?')\" href=\"a_del_vendor.php?id=".$data['id']."\" ><input type='image' src='images/icn_trash.png' title='Trash'></a></td> ";

                                        echo "</tr>";
                                }        
                    echo "</table>";
                    echo '<div class="pagination" style="margin-left:300px;" >';
                            if ($total_pages > 1) 
                                {
                                    echo paginate($reload, $show_page, $total_pages);
                                }
                        echo "</ul>
                    </div>";
                ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="submit_link">
              <input type="submit" value="Send Mail" name="submit" class="alt_btn">
        </div>
    </footer>
</form>
```

Comment: is the table inside a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `<table>` is wrapped in a `<form>` tag. Use an `<img />` tag instead. Using `<input type="image" />` will actually [submit](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PRBP3G) the form rather than to perform a link redirection.

```
echo "
<td>
    <a href=\"a_add_fav_vendor.php?id=".$data['id']."\">
        <img src=\"images/icn_edit.png\" title=\"Edit\"
    </a>
</td>
";
```

Comment: my table is inside a form but i am using the form to multi select options and then send mail, and for edit i have kept a direct link. i have updated the post

Comment: @sammy yes that would definitely submit the form instead of having a redirection, you should change it to an `<img>` tag instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
echo '<td><a href="/a_add_fav_vendor.php?id="'.$data['id'].'"><input type="image" src="images/icn_edit.png" title="Edit"></a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do some Change like

```
echo "<td><a href='a_add_fav_vendor.php?id=".$data['id']."'><input type='image' src='images/icn_edit.png' title='Edit'></a></td> ";
```

Comment: it is still not redirecting

Comment: @sammy If it is still not redirecting then why you approved Ghost's above answer?

Comment: Working well check in other page with only     echo "<td><a href='a_add_fav_vendor.php?id=".$data['id']."'><input type='image' src='images/icn_edit.png' title='Edit'></a></td> ";